# Actualización gráfico excel en formulario access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, oledb

tengo un formulario de access donde he incluido un gráfico de excel como unbound ole object. La hoja excel es un archivo independiente, fuera de la base de datos. Mediante una instrucción DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet logro exportar los resultados de una consulta de access a la hoja excel. El gráfico en excel se actualiza solo, pero no se ve en el formulario, y no sé como forzar la actualización. He intentado actualizar con la instrucción .requery, pero no se actualiza. Si abro el objeto manualmente desde el formulario sí lo hace.

¿algún modo de que se actualice inmediatamente después de hacer la exportación?

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Pero los datos del gráfico... ¿salen todos de la base de datos? ¿Por qué no lo haces directamente en Access?

Comment: Ya lo he hecho, y el problema con las gráficas de access es que pierden espontáneamente el formato de las series, puntos, etc cada dos por tres, además de que su aspecto es más pobre y limitado que los gráficos de excel. De ahí que intente hacerlo a través de insertar un gráfico de excel.

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que he llegado a una solución: crear un bounded frame y vincularlo a la hoja excel. Cuando los datos de la gráfica se actualizan, si se fija el foco en el frame, se actualiza bien. Lo he automatizado con vba y para mí funciona.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.

Comment: @candelaria y es posible autoaceptar tu propia respuesta??? Y ganas reputación por hacer eso???